# Erro ao tentar conectar ao SQL Server à partir de webservice em IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wcf

Estou recebendo alguns erros ao tentar realizar uma consulta no SQL Server à partir de um WebService hospedado em um servidor IIS 7.5.

Minha connectionString no web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="TESTEPENDENCIA" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:179.191.87.22; User ID=SISTEMA; Password=SYSUSER;Initial Catalog=TESTEPENDENCIA; timeout=100" />  
</connectionStrings>
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="TESTEPENDENCIA" />
```

Erro retornado pelo browser:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)"

Caso retire o protocolo "tcp" do Data Source, o seguinte erro é retornado:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Os dois erros ocorrem ao tentar acessar bancos de dados em servidores diferentes.

O interessante é que, em um outro servidor IIS (que infelizmente não consigo ver a versão, mas que roda em um Windows Server 2003), o acesso ao banco ocorre normalmente.

Dei uma olhada nas configurações mais fáceis do servidor IIS, porém não possuo muito conhecimento para inferir alguma configuração somente à partir disso. Minha ideia inicial era que talvez a aplicação estivesse buscando alguma connectionString herdada, porém esse não parece ser o caso, já que ao remover a tag do `web.config` local o mesmo reclama a falta dela.

Comment: Usando o `IIS Express` (ambiente de desenvolvimento) funciona numa boa?

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta (como disse, sou praticamente um completo leigo em ISS). O ISS Express não é uma versão mais leve e limitada do ISS? Ou há um outro modo de eu testar a minha aplicação no servidor que não a padrão?

Comment: Na máquina em que você desenvolveu o `webservice` funciona normal? O `ISS Express` é a ferramenta usada para testar aplicações web em desenvolvimento (geralmente o visual studio inicia ela por si próprio)

Comment: Ah sim, perdão. Sim, na máquina o webservice funciona normalmente.

Comment: Veja [este link](http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331)

Answer (score 1):

O problema era um bloqueio de acesso por IP no servidor SQL. O IIS 7.5 estava na mesma rede que o SQL e eu estava usando um IP externo para acessá-lo, mas deveria usar um IP interno. O outro servidor acessava exatamente porque estava em outra rede.

Aparentemente, os erros apresentados são genéricos e indicam apenas que a aplicação não conseguiu acessar o banco de dados.